# Pascal array definition error

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I am a 1st grade student and I got a task to complete, but cannot understand how to avoid errors that I got. Could you please help me?
Here is my code:

```
PROGRAM LAB5MAS (INPUT,OUTPUT);
CONST
      n=5;
      m=6;
VAR
A: array[1..n,1..m] of Integer;
R: array[m-1] of Integer;
i,j: Integer;
max: Integer;
BEGIN
  Randomize;
  for i:=1 to n do
    for j:=1 to m do
      a[i,j]:=random(10);
  Writeln('a=,');
  for i:=1 to n do
  BEGIN
    for j:=1 to m do
      write(a[i,j]:4);
    writeln;
  END;
  for i:=1 to n do
    for j:=1 to m-1 do
      R[i,j]:=abs(A[i,j]-A[i,j+1]);
END.

for i:=1 to n do
BEGIN
  max:=R[i,1];
  for j:=1 to m-1 do
  if R[i,j] > max then
  max:=R[i,j];
  Writeln(max);
END;
for i:=1 to n do
BEGIN
  for j:=1 to m do
  write(a[i,j]:4);
  writeln;
END.
```

And the errors that I got:

```
Compiling C:\Users\Nadia\Desktop\qqwww\laba.pas
laba.pas(7,17) Error: Error in type definition
laba.pas(24,7) Error: Illegal qualifier
laba.pas(26,1) Fatal: There were 2 errors compiling module, stopping
Fatal: Compilation aborted
```

How to fix this?
And how to compute the biggest value of subtraction between nearest elements in array A(5,6) and write this result to array B?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: LAST TIME i PROGRAMMED IN pASCAL WAS IN THE HIGH SCHOOL.... BUT IT SEEMS THAT `R` IS DEFINED AS 1 DIMENSIN ARRAY WHILE YOU ARE USING AS MATRIX `R[I,J]` (ALSO THE DEFINITION OF `R` SHOULD BE `ARRAY [1..M-1] OF INTEGER;`

Comment: Pascal does not take a simple subscript for defining arrays; you must provide the entire range of subscripts that are expected to be valid. Your definition of `R` is incorrect. Look at how you defined the valid subscripts for `A` in the line above. Furthermore, you are trying to use `R` as a two-dimensional array, when it has not been defined as such. Go back and desk-check your code.

Comment: You have two `END.` (`END` ending with a period). That's going to be a syntax error. The syntactical end of your Pascal program is at the end of the first `END.`.

Comment: Also note that it looks as if the first part, up to the first `END.` should be a separate procedure. Which Pascal dialect is this?

Answer (score 2):

> R: array[m-1] of Integer;

This is wrong, you need to specify a range of values, e.g. "R: array[0..m-1] of Integer;"

> R[i,j]:=abs(A[i,j]-A[i,j+1]);

You are trying to treat a one dimesntional array as a multidimensional array.

You also seem to have screwed up your "END"s, I think what you have in that regard is syntatically correct but almost certainly not what you intended (iirc everything after the first "END." is ignored)